# How to use the DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder to gett the Hex code

Tags: netty

I am using netty4.0 to cache tcp data from a device. and the following is my pipline handlers as following,

```
    pipeline.addLast("frame", new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(8019,Delimiters.lineDelimiter()));
    pipeline.addLast("decoder", stringDecoder);
    pipeline.addLast("handler", serverHandler);
    pipeline.addLast("encoder", stringEncoder);
```

I have two questions:

1. which decoder method will be used in DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder, which has two decoders; Do I need create another class to extends the DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder?
2. Why I always get some strange code "$$..0.....@..y..", but the real hex is "24 24 00 11 30 06 00 00 00 19 40 00 02 79 1d 0d 0a"; How can I get the later one?

Thanks in advance, and I am new in the network stream, please forgive.

Comment: You should be able to use DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder as is. It will use the two decode methods internally as required. As for your other questions can you supply more detail? For example what is the protocol message format? How are you logging them? Are you explicitly setting the expected charset when creating the string decoder / encoder?

Comment: thanks! what i understand from your answer is that the decode methods would be both invoked. right? concerning the protocol, in fact the data come from a gps device, which should be bytes stream. currently, I want to get the HEX directly, so I am not sure how to get the HEX.

Comment: Just to clarify - you're receiving a byte stream and you want to convert the bytes received into a Hex string? The bytes you are receiving do not represent a hex encoded string? Also is it a pure stream or does the stream contain discrete messages that you need to read and, if so, how are the messages delimited?